# Is it possible to Add Attachments to my Mail App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, email-attachments, flurry

I want to add attachments to my Mail App Is it possible?
I am sending mails and  receiving mails in my Application but i dont know how to send attachments through mail. please give me a solution for this

Thanks,
 Anand

I am Exchanging the messages using with Furry SDK And Webservices, But i need to send Attachments. Or How to send Bytes to Webservices?

In Webservice if we pass string we are using "@"

What we use when we pass Binary Data to Webservice?

In My App Soap for Data is

```
NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
                     <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\
                     <soap12:Body>\
                     <InsertAttachmentint xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\
                     <Filename>string</Filename>\
                     <FileType>string</FileType>\
                     <FileContentint>base64Binary</FileContentint>\
                     </InsertAttachmentint>\
                     </soap12:Body>\
                     </soap12:Envelope>"];
```

In the above soap We use "%@"  in the Place of String,  What about base64Binary?

Comment: How are you sending mails? Are you using the message framework?

Comment: No, im using Flury SDK for E-mailing.

Comment: I Want to save files in server or how to send bytes to Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this
NSString *str_html = @"Content of file";
NSString *filenameForSub = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Fr.cvs",str_date];
    NSData *myData = [str_html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

    [mailController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/cvs" fileName:filenameForSub];
    [mailController setMessageBody:filenameForSub isHTML:YES];
```

go to this link

http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/04/30/Send-file-%28images%29-to-web-server-using-POST-method.aspx

Comment: i want to Send data to Server through Webservice.. How Can i Send it?

Answer (score 0):

The workings of attachments are defined in [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) (see that Wikipedia article for an overview of MIME and the many RFCs that define how it works).

An attachment is simply a *part* in a multipart message with a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header. This is described in [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183).

---

EDIT: You mention that you’re using Flurry to send email. Can you link to any documentation, or provide any example code for how email works in Flurry?